# IOS app is greyed out after pressing home

Tags: ios

I have an IOS swift app that I'm working on that seems to run fine.  When I press the home button to exit it while running, the app icon turns grey and I can't go back into the app nor delete it.  The only way tot go back is if I double tap the home button and find the app under all the running apps.  What is causing this issue?

I was trying to change the app name and maybe messed up some setting because even earlier iteration of the app doesn't work so it's not a bug in code.

Comment: ??? Share a screenshot.

Comment: Maybe it's an iOS 11 bug? Have you tried `turning off and on the device`?